# Navigation view with fragment. Toolbar

Tags: android, tabs, navigationview

So, I have an activity with navigation view. By click on its item I change fragment in activity. All fragment have the same toolbar. But one have this toolbar and TabLayout to it. I would like to know what is better to declare toolbar once on activity like this

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

or declare it in each fragment.

The disadvantage of the first method is default toolbar shadow. When I add tabs in fragment, shadow looks like

[image]

When I tried 2 solution. All my toolbar was with back icon instead drawer animated logo.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I had the exact same problem. This is how I solved it:

- Move the toolbars to the fragments like you suggested (so you won't have a shadow separating the two). This allows for a way more flexible way to implement (different) toolbars in your layouts too.
- Replace the Toolbar's navigation icon by a custom one like this:

  ```
  toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_menu);
  ```

(I used the [Android Asset Studio](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-actionbar.html#source.type=clipart&source.space.trim=0&source.space.pad=0&source.clipart=res%2Fclipart%2Ficons%2Fnavigation_menu.svg&name=ic_action_navigation_menu&theme=light&color=33b5e5%2C60/) to easily create an icon with the preferred color)

- Now open the NavigationView with the new menu(home) icon. You can do this through the MainActivity (the one with the NavigationView). Create a public method in that Activity that opens the drawer:

  ```
  public void openDrawer(){
      mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
  }
  ```
- Now call this method in the OnOptionsItemSelected in your fragments like this:

  ```
  @Override
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
      // handle item selection
      switch (item.getItemId()) {
          case android.R.id.home: //Menu icon
              ((MainActivity)getActivity()).openDrawer();
              return true;            
          default:
              return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
      }
  }
  ```

That's it. Of course the downside is that you must implement the Toolbar in each Fragment. However, this is the only way (that I know of) that enables you to have the Toolbar (+TabLayout) in a Fragment and still be able to control your NavigationView.

Answer (score 0):

You can use AppBarLayout from design support library like:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            ...
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            ...
            />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

and then you can change visibility of tablayout.

For more information about desing layout library : [link](https://medium.com/ribot-labs/exploring-the-new-android-design-support-library-b7cda56d2c32)

Comment: So I need to do something like 

`mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        TabLayout tabs = ((MyActivity) getActivity()).getTabLayout();
        tabs.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        tabs.setupWithViewPager(mPager);`

 Look not good.